# Batch file ERROR: Invalid argument/option when trying to delete folder

Tags: batch-file

I have two commands that I'm trying to use to delete old files and folders.

**The first command:**

```
forfiles /p "%DELETEPATH%" -s  /D -%date% /C "cmd /c del /f /q @path"
```

This is working fine and deleting all the contents in the path.

**The second command:**

```
forfiles /p "%DELETEPATH%" -s /D -%date% /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE RMDIR /S /Q @path"
```

It is returning me with error Invalid argument/option.

I intend to use the second command because the first one just delete the contents and I'm left with empty folders which I do not want to be present.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is it complaining about the `date` variable? Please paste full error output.

Comment: No, not about the date. The date format is good, its only that the second command being run is returning with "ERROR:  Invalid argument/option".

Comment: The obvous difference between your two examples is that the latter does not have surrounding double quotes around %DELETEPATH%.

Comment: Compo, thanks for your reply and please excuse me for the typo.

When i run the 2 commands, sometimes I get "ERROR: The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: The issue has been fixed. Thanks a lot for your replies.

The thing is that when the first command is being executed the folder's date is being updated to "now". This causes the second command to be useless as the minimum date that can be set to delete is 1. 

Therefore just running the second command is working fine.

Answer (score 3):

For anybody having this issue and finding this unanswered question the solution is to remove the quotes around the source path.

Placing quotes around the source path will cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

According to:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551(v=ws.11).aspx

the format of the date has to be using / (0/0/0)instead of - (0-0-0)
but what you can also do if i understood it correctly you can use
/D +0 for checking for +0 days

Comment: Yes, thanks for your reply.

The issue is that I'm facing is the second command.

Comment: @cama is it maybe possible that the /S and the /Q have to be /s and /q

Answer (score 0):

D:\logs>forfiles -P "d:\logs" -S -M *.* -D -3 -C "CMD /C DEL @path"
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '@path'.
Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.

D:\logs>forfiles -P "d:\logs" -S -M *.* -D -3 -C "CMD /C DEL d:\logs"
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'd:\logs"'.
Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.

D:\logs>forfiles

"2022-01-06.rar"
"2022-01-07.rar"
"2022-01-08.rar"
"2022-01-09.rar"

D:\logs>forfiles -P "d:\logs" -S -M *.* -D -3 -C "CMD /C DEL @path"
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '@path'.
Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.

Finally, The below command worked and we should not put " in the source path.

D:\logs>forfiles -P d:\logs\ -S -M *.* -D -3 -C "CMD /C DEL @path"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).